# Occasionally missing players

Tags: savage-worlds

I am planning to start a homebrew fantasy savage worlds campaign with my friends over roll20.

We have already played together in a d&d 5e campaign over the past year and now starting a new one.

The problem is that all of us have pretty busy schedules, which means that each session, at least one of the players will be missing. The problem existed in the previous campaign too, the differnce is that I used a pretty railroady campaign and now I want a more homebrew open world kind of adventure.

How can i run a meaningful adventure keeping that in mind?

Comment: What genre is it you are running? Is it from a published setting or is it homebrew? How many players do you have in total, and how many do you expect to run the game with on average?

Comment: Homebrew fantasy.  There are 6 players and i expect that each session there will be 4-5 players

Comment: It's not clear to me how this situation is any different than your D&D scenario. How does bring open world make things different than before?